# Why android device id change when i am debugging?

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, deviceid

We have and old App Works perfect in all devices for all this years, except in a New Samsung Note8.

The problem is that Android Studio change the DeviceId of this Smartphone without any reason, Seems to be imposible, but it's true.

Every time that we debug our APP, the Deviceid Change.

This is an important problem for us, because we use this ID for to control our licenses.

Any Idea?

PD: Still can´t belive it!

Comment: are you running app in real device?

Comment: There's no way Android Studio is responsible for anything beside pushing a built APK to your phone. Follow the Android Developers blog. Start here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html It may be because of Android 8. It may be because Samsung is special.

Comment: Yes. We are running in a real device.

This Note8 actualy is in Android 8,  and AndroidStudio in 3.1. Previous version (7.1) wasn´t a problem.

Comment: Then the solution is simple: Don't deinstall the app. If you only update the app the ANDROID_ID should remain constant.

Comment: We are just debugging. AndroidStudio change the DeviceId, doesn´t matter if we install or deinstall...

Comment: Have you InstantRun enabled or disabled? May be this is a side-effect of Instant-Run. Or do you use different signing keys? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729916/same-android-id-in-oreo) ANDROID_ID should not change unsless you change the signing key. Check your debug key (too old?) and/or specify a fixed one.

Comment: Well then install the app from command line. `gradlew installDebug` This will rule out Android Studio's fault... Post the code you use to get the ID. There are many IDs, I'd like to know *exactly* which you use.

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 1):

DeviceId changes if you change the signature of the application

I.e if you are making your 1st release and then you try make another release with the new key.jks then you will find the
DeviceId in 1st release is different then the DeviceId in second release

Conclusion :- always generate signed APK with the same key.jks